# symbol not found , like mathfrak s

Tags: symbols

guide us to find this symbol, we are struggling to find this symbol ,

we used `$\mathfrak s$` for this, but no exact output came.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-alphabet

Comment: we used detexify and we cant found the symbol there

Comment: Is it possible a font that does this and not a symbol?

Comment: This is, IMHO, truly a fraktur `s` in some unusual calligraphy. Your only option would then be to find yourself a font that looks like this, and use it.

Comment: What context was this used in?

Comment: Are you maybe looking to use [mtpro2 (Mathtime Professional 2)](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) package? It features `\mathfrak` for both uppercase *and* lowercase letters. The full package isn't free of charge. However, you needn't purchase the full package to use the `\mathfrak` command -- obtaining the package's "lite" subset, which is free of charge, will do.