# text mode of a latex symbol \mathfrak s not found

Tags: symbols

hi i need the text mode of a latex symbol, in a reference pdf doc i found the exact symbol

which is categorized under "text" category. attached the screenshot of the pdf. i need a

different output of \mathfrak s

[image]

Comment: There is no built-in distinction between appearances of symbols in text and math, contrary to what that table seems to imply. Unicode classifies *characters*, not their representation.

Comment: This question looks like the same as your previous http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130462/27635

Comment: im asking the symbol which looks like red marked, but \mathfrak {s} not giving the same output

Comment: @karlkoeller yeah this time i got a reference document for that symbol which may helpful for us to find exact output

Comment: Why don't you add this information in your previous question and delete this one?

Comment: @ravi Is the one in my answer the one you were looking for?

Answer (score 5):

The table snippet you show seems to imply that there's a canonical representation of Fraktur in text and in math. This isn't true.

There are some fonts in Fraktur style available; one of them (available with the `yfonts` package) happens to print the ‘s’ as in the left column (the one marked by you), another one (Euler Fraktur, provided by the AMS) has no terminal swash.

Here's a way to produce the two glyphs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{yfonts}

\begin{document}
\textfrak{s:} is not the same
as $\mathfrak{s}$, because
they use different fonts.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I've probably found the symbol you are looking for:

[image]

The command to obtain it is `\mfraks` and requires `xits-math` font and `unicode-math` package, which implies you have to compile with xelatex or lualatex.

MWE:

```
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}

\begin{document}
$\mfraks$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are asking for the plain text equivalent of `\mathfrak{s}`. It is U+1D530 MATHEMATICAL FRAKTUR SMALL S. Note that it is outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), which may cause problems in processing it in many programs (as it has to represented as a surrogate pair in UTF-16). Moreover, [font support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d530/fontsupport.htm) is very limited.

Comment: i need that exact symbol which i marked red box in my doc, how i can do this