# What is the font?

Tags: symbols

I already tried to use [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) but the closest suggestion was `\mathfrak{Y}`. I'm sure that it is not the case.

Does anybody have idea how to produce the letter used for the space cited on the image?

[image]

Comment: do you have the pdf, or is that a scan of paper?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, unfortunately it is a scanned Fox's paper from JSTOR. No info about the fonts.

Comment: @Sigur It looks like a `\mathfrak{Y}`, for instance from `esstix` fonts (see [`mathalfa`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalfa)).

Comment: @Manuel, thanks. I guess that you are right. The page 5 from the documentation has the glyph. Please, feel free to post an answer with screen shot (I can edit and insert it if you wish).

Comment: Isn't this off topic?

Comment: @Manuel, I don't think so.

Comment: Sigur, just out of interest, would you post the link to the JSTOR page?

Comment: @A.Donda, here is the file http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969292

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It certainly looks like a `\mathfrak{Y}`, for instance from `esstix` fonts (see [`mathalfa`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalfa)).

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I can not use the `mathpi` font. But `esstix` is very close.

Answer (score 1):

You can as well use the `yfonts` package, following @egreg's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131832/text-mode-of-a-latex-symbol-mathfrak-s-not-found).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\begin{document}
    \textfrak{Y}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But it is not so close.